# How to get section-facts-description-text in Google Maps using python?

Tags: python, google-maps, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the `section-facts-description-text` in Google Maps.

I have tried this code already:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.google.co.id/maps/place/Semarang,+Kota+Semarang,+Jawa+Tengah/@-7.0247703,110.3488077,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x2e708b4d3f0d024d:0x1e0432b9da5cb9f2!8m2!3d-7.0051453!4d110.4381254"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

for strong_tag in soup.find_all('span',{'class':'section-facts-description-text'}):
    print strong_tag.text, strong_tag.next_sibling
```

What's wrong with my code? Is there anything I'm missing? Is there any option to do that action with library or API in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`urllib` requests the initial loading data off of a webpage and then terminates. In the case of many complex non-static webpages, Google Maps included, that payload consists almost entirely of JavaScript scripts, which *then* populate the page as you know it.

So instead of downloading the DOM elements and so on that you want, you're downloading the JavaScript that populates everything instead.

In order to pull down the loaded GMaps page instead, you'll need to use a web driver that's capable of opening the page, waiting until it's loaded, and only *then* downloading the content. For that you should investigate [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).